# Removing outer border of toggle button wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I have looked through numerous questions where people want to mess with borders of their buttons. I am using a toggle button (WPF) and it seems like there is an 'inner' border and an 'outer' border. I can manage to change the inner boarder to red, but I have no clue how to change the color of the outer border, or even get rid of it. I have gotten rid of the chrome button or whatever that comes with the aero theme, but I still cannot change this border. This is the picture of what I am getting for toggle buttons:

[image]

As you can see there is white in the borders. Here is my code for that style:

```
<Style x:Key="Style1" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Button BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Foreground="White">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Button>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I am using it like this:

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Single" Name="touchPanel"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Black" BorderThickness="0">
        <RadioButton Width="60" Height="60" Name="mouseTouchSelection" IsChecked="True" Content="Mouse" Style="{DynamicResource RadioButtonStyle1}" />
        <RadioButton Width="60" Height="60" Name="panTouchSelection"  BorderThickness="0"  Content="Pan" Style="{DynamicResource RadioButtonStyle1}"  />
        <RadioButton Width="60" Height="60" Name="rotateTouchSelection" Content="Rotate" Style="{DynamicResource RadioButtonStyle1}"/>
        <RadioButton Width="60" Height="60" Name="zoomBoxTouchSelection" Content="Box Zoom" Style="{DynamicResource RadioButtonStyle1}" />
    </ListBox>
```

But what I would like the buttons to look like is:

[image]

I achieved the above buttons by just overriding the default button style, but I can't seem to do it with the Toggle Button. I tried overriding Radio Button also, and I had the same problem. What am I missing? Can I somehow use the Button style instead of the toggle button style? I am just starting to learn Styles, so don't be to harsh! Appreciate all input though!

Comment: I have Windows8 and your style works perfectly fine for me with no white borders around it.

Comment: Lame. I am running windows 7, any idea why that might happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only tested it with Buttons, RadioButtons, and ToggleButtons, but the problem  arises when trying to nest buttons withing a listbox. So I switched the code from:

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Single" Name="touchPanel"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Black" BorderThickness="0">
        <RadioButton Width="60" Height="60" Name="mouseTouchSelection" IsChecked="True" Content="Mouse" Style="{DynamicResource RadioButtonStyle1}" />
        <RadioButton Width="60" Height="60" Name="panTouchSelection"  BorderThickness="0"  Content="Pan" Style="{DynamicResource RadioButtonStyle1}"  />
        <RadioButton Width="60" Height="60" Name="rotateTouchSelection" Content="Rotate" Style="{DynamicResource RadioButtonStyle1}"/>
        <RadioButton Width="60" Height="60" Name="zoomBoxTouchSelection" Content="Box Zoom" Style="{DynamicResource RadioButtonStyle1}" />
    </ListBox>
```

to:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2">
        <RadioButton Width="60" Height="60" Name="mouseTouchSelection" IsChecked="True" Content="Mouse" Style="{DynamicResource RadioButtonStyle1}" />
        <RadioButton Width="60" Height="60" Name="panTouchSelection"  BorderThickness="0"  Content="Pan" Style="{DynamicResource RadioButtonStyle1}"  />
        <RadioButton Width="60" Height="60" Name="rotateTouchSelection" Content="Rotate" Style="{DynamicResource RadioButtonStyle1}"/>
        <RadioButton Width="60" Height="60" Name="zoomBoxTouchSelection" Content="Box Zoom" Style="{DynamicResource RadioButtonStyle1}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

and I got the visual results I wanted (we will see if they work properly).

Answer (score 0):

The Button in your controltemplate is creating the extra borders.  If you replace Button with a Border you can style the togglebutton borders. Is there a reason you're using a Button? You can use triggers to provide the button behavior if needed. See below:

```
        <Style x:Key="Style1" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"  SnapsToDevicePixels="true" >
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>                            
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CheckedBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Why did you set `BorderThickness` to `0` in a `Setter`, when you have explicitly overridden it by setting it to `1` on the `Border` named `Border`?